# File defined in \output is not generated

Tags: tex-core, output

My sample tex file is as follows

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\immediate\openout5=sample

\immediate\write5{ \noexpand\documentstyle[12pt]{article} }
\immediate\write5{ \noexpand\begin{document} }

\immediate\write5{Hello Hello}

\immediate\write5{ \noexpand\end{document} }
\immediate\closeout5

\end{document}
```

Why am I not seeing any sample.tex or sample.aux file generated in my current directory?

Comment: it will not write an `aux` file of course, but that writes `sample.tex` when I run it.

Comment: show the log file you get from the above test file. (you can use the `{}` button in the editor to mark as a code section, as I did for your tex file)

Comment: Hello David, I am using MikTex on Windows. I see the message in the console window that log file is generated. But I do not see the file in the working directory. Any help on where to locate it?

Comment: oh well your sample.tex is probably written to same place as the test file .log are you using the --output-directory command line option?

Comment: just use the windows search facility to search for a file called sample.tex

Comment: David, Also thanks for editing the code in the right way! I am new to stackexchange - i mean in asking the questions :-)

Comment: Tried - that but as you know windows search is not same as linux find! But I am trying again.

Comment: You are an _expert_ at asking questions now: you have asked more questions than @egreg and myself combined:-)

Answer (score 1):

If you name the file `sample.tex`, then running `pdflatex` on it will overwrite the file. Indeed, after running

```
pdflatex sample
```

in a working directory over that code named `sample.tex`, the directory will contain

```
jagnan > ls
sample.aux  sample.log  sample.tex
```

and `cat sample.tex` will show

```
 \documentstyle [12pt]{article} 
 \begin {document} 
Hello Hello
 \end {document}
```

However, depending on your operating system, the result of overwriting the file can be different, maybe leading to unsuccessful runs.

If I save your code under the name `jagnan.tex`, then running `pdflatex jagnan` the directory will be populated with

```
jagnan > ls
jagnan.aux  jagnan.log  jagnan.tex  sample.tex
```

Comment: Hello egreg, I am not naming this sample code as sample.tex. I have named it as expr003.tex. As I commented above, I am not using it on linux but on windows. I am not able to locate the .aux or .log files in the working directory. But the console window in MikTex says that the file is generated. I dont know where.

Comment: @JagNaN If you name the file differently from `sample.tex`, then only `sample.tex` will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

When I run pdflatex from shell with argument -output-directory it generates all the files in the specified directory - .log .aux and also the sample.tex.

`pdflatex -output-directory . experiment003.tex`

This is what I did to set the configuration in TexWorks:

1. Go to Edit->Preferences->Typesetting tab
2. In the Processing tools section click on '+' to add a new tool
3. Names this tool as say 'mytex'
4. Select 'pdflatex.exe' (from correct directory) as the program to be used
5. Add '-output-directory=.' and '$fullname' as the arguments
6. Optionally you may want to change its position in the dropdown or set it as default program

In case you need to change it for existing commands, you need to check the documentation about command line argument for each of the program used and set it appropriately.

Thanks David and egreg for all the help and pointers.

Comment: you mean that the current directory isn't the default? that is weird:-) where does it send stuff by default? (`--output-directory` causes so many problems using it by default would be a strange choice for teh editor)

Comment: Hello David, I am not sure if that is set as default. The reason I am not sure is because I did not install MiKTeX on Windows as an admin. So it is possible that some settings may be different when users with admin privileges install it. Kindly take my answer as a solution in the situation where .log and .aux files are not getting generated in the current working directory.